# Chrome Extension: Returned Window Variable not updating in extension, but updating in Page Source

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm running into an issue with my Chrome Extension. I am able to use Chrome's "View page source" option to see a certain variable both before and after a page is updated dynamically.  However, by using our injected script, we are only able to pull the variable from before the page is updated dynamically.  We can see in the page source that the variable appears to be updated, but we don't know if content scripts simply can't pull updated variables or if there is some issue with using injections for this particular problem.

I haven't been able to find any similar issue where an extension needs to be able to keep up with dynamically updated pages and their variables and thus am at a loss.

```
inject() {
    function propagateVariable(handShake) {
      var message = { handShake };
      message['window'] = staticVariableName;
      window.postMessage(message, "*");
    }

    if (document.getElementById('myExtensionNode')) {
      var elem = document.getElementById('myExtensionNode');
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
    
    var script = `( ${propagateVariable.toString()} )('${this.handshakeKey}');`
    var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    var scriptBody = document.createTextNode(script);

    scriptTag.id = 'myExtensionNode';
    scriptTag.appendChild(scriptBody);
    document.body.append(scriptTag);
  }
```

I have this script tied to a listener and a mutation observer to watch for dynamic updates to the pages, with logic to look for specific changes that we're interested in.  Essentially, consider this tied to a button press such that I can get the variable whenever I press the button.

If you have any insight or need any further information I'll try to update my post as necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: This fragment of code is correct and will read a global variable `staticVariableName` from page context. So, the only explanation is that the variable is not updated or you didn't run this whole code at the time when the variable actually was updated. P.S. You can remove the script tag immediately after it ran because there's no need to keep it in DOM.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for looking it over.  I've also taken your advice and am removing the injected script much earlier.  Unfortunately I'm pretty confident that both the variable is updating and I am running it at a time where it's been updated.  I can change the page from its initial state to a second state, then ten minutes later I can change it to a third state, and I am still being returned the variable from the first state.  Viewing the page source does show the global variable has updated even before my "Page updated, running script" message initializes.

Comment: Once a variable exists, its value is not related to changes in html source. The value changes either by an already running JavaScript code or when a new script element is added that redefines the same variable.