# why is the following javascript function binding not working?

Tags: javascript, events, google-chrome-extension, event-handling, dom-events

I am binding to a function `myfunc`  where I set `this.enforcement`
Then I am injecting a script to a page via javascript.
but `myfunc()` is not getting called.

```
class MyClass {

  constructor() {
    this.enforcement = undefined
    window.myfunc = this.myfunc.bind(this);
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.src = "https://tcr9i.chat.openai.com/v2/35536E1E-65B4-4D96-9D97-6ADB7EFF8147/api.js";
    script.async = !0;
    script.defer = !0;
    script.setAttribute('data-callback', 'myfunc')
    document.body.appendChild(script)
  }

  myfunc(enforcement) {
    this.enforcement = enforcement
    alert("enforcement set")
    enforcement.setConfig({
      onCompleted: (r) => {
        console.debug('enforcement.onCompleted', r)
      },
      onReady: () => {
        console.debug('enforcement.onReady')
      },
      onError: (r) => {
        console.debug('enforcement.onError', r)
      },
      onFailed: (r) => {
        console.debug('enforcement.onFailed', r)
      },
    })
  }

  async getEforcement() {
    if (!this.enforcement) {
      alert("no enforcement found") // <- it is always reaching here since setting of `this.enforcement` inside `myfunc` is not happening
      return
    }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.pendingPromises = [{ resolve, reject }]
      this.enforcement.run()
    })
  }

}
```

I am calling `getEforcement()` explicitly on pageload but still the `myfunc` is not getting called.

As debugging steps, I have verified the script is getting properly embedded in my desided page and the src is working, I have put a breakpoint inside `api.js` and verified that it is not entering it. I am not sure how to debug the triggering of the event not happening part.

Comment: How `myfun` is called? where?

Comment: @YuvarajM I have this line `script.setAttribute('data-callback', 'myfunc')` My understanding is  it will trigger.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 That does not call the function. Does the openai documentation describe that this would work?

Comment: @Bergi Well I have another piece of code where when I run `api.js` on console it enters the `myfunc()` , I am just trying to debug why it is not entering this new piece of code which I am trying to write following it. That code too apparently have nothing more than `window.myfunc = this.myfunc.bind(this);` and `script.setAttribute('data-callback', 'myfunc')`. I have searched that code entirely and sure it has no mention of `myfunc` anywhere else.

Comment: If you have another piece of code that attempts to do the same thing, it's probable interfering here, since `window.myfunc` is global and you can have only one of it

Comment: @Bergi sorry for the confusion. I mean another big repo from where I am trying to learn injecting/enforcement logic. I don't have that code running in browser at this moment.  moreover I named `myfunc` differently here.

Comment: @Bergi I don't have full clarity how the `enforcement` argument is sent to the `myfunc()`. the script `api.js` do have reference of `enforcement`  but if I run `api.js` on console it returns `true`

Comment: @Bergi since the function in the `api.js` executes immediately after definition my understanding was it calls the `data-callback` function once the file is loaded with last value inside it ie `arkoseLabsClientApi385154e0` as data to `myfunc()`. And since we are doing `window.myfunc = this.myfunc.bind(this);`,
 just call to `myfunc()` will transfer control to `this.myfunc()` . Can you clear the wrong part in my understanding here.

Comment: @Bergi I guess the difference with the repo from where I am trying to learn is that there it might be able to run the script immediately after injecting it, while in my case it is successfully injected in the page but not running it immediately after (I dont know why). I guess that's why `defer=true` is for . isn't it ?

Comment: calling `myfunc()` will call the myfunc instance of the most recently instantiated `MyClass` with no argument, therefore `enforcement` function argument will be `undefined`

Comment: @JaromandaX Why will it not transfer control from window function the myclass's function? I am doing doing `window.myfunc = this.myfunc.bind(this)` after all.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 I cannot see what *api.js* does, it might help if you could add the relevant part of the code to your question. But the script does not execute immediately after injecting it, it needs to load first. If something else is overwriting `window.myfunc` in the meantime, your class method will not get called.

Comment: yes, so calling `myfunc()` (rather than `instance.myfunc()` ) will call the most recently instantiated instance of `MyClass` with `this` being that most recently instantiated instance ... you are doing `new MyClass` somewhere, aren't you

Comment: @Bergi this is the link  https://tcr9i.chat.openai.com/v2/35536E1E-65B4-4D96-9D97-6ADB7EFF8147/api.js clicking it doesn't work ?

Comment: @ishandutta2007 Oh I can load the file just fine, but I cannot understand what it does, it's an unreadable mess. Do you have a non-minified version of it? Also you should add the relevant part of it to your question anyway, as the link will rot.

Comment: @Bergi not sure I can find with original variable name, but this is beautified version, https://github.com/jeffara/superpower-chatgpt/blob/main/v2/35536E1E-65B4-4D96-9D97-6ADB7EFF8147/api.js

Comment: @Bergi and `$t` is probably the `enforcement` object that we are looking for

Comment: @JaromandaX yes I am doing `new MyClass` somewhere and on that instance I am calling `getEforcement()` and was expecting `this.enforcement` to be ready as preparing `this.enforcement` was part of the constructor but unfortunately found it is still not ready.

Comment: @Bergi update: on console I see error on line `document.body.appendChild(script);` saying`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED` even though the script tag is visible and clickable.

Comment: Well then that's your problem. The `<script>` element being visible in the DOM (or not) says nothing about the code having been executed.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63620236/865220 I solved the loading issue but I am still back to square1, the loaded script is still not being executed on load.

Comment: you set `this.enforcement = undefined` in the constructor ... and then you set `this.enforcement = enforcement` in function `myfunc(enforcement)` - which you call like `myfunc()` ... so ... of course `this.enforcement` starts out as `undefined` and continues to be undefined since that's the only thing you assign to it

Comment: @JaromandaX if `myfunc()` gets called via `data-callback` it wont remain undefined as it would execute `this.enforcement = enforcement`. The issue is it isn't getting called. not sure I understand the point you are trying to make, but isn't this what we are debugging ?

Comment: do you cal `new MyClass` more than once? then that will be the problem

Comment: `it would execute this.enforcement = enforcement` ... so, how is `myfunc` being called? `myfunc()` or `myfunc(something)` ... you don't show anything about how it's called in the question, except you DO say it's called using `myfunc()`... which means the argument is `undefined` which means you are setting `this.enforcement = undefined` ... sorry ... I only comment about code in the question, and the code in the questions lacks detail

Comment: @Bergi more debugging update: actually the `api.js` is running properly after load, but  seems like when it is executing no`window.myfunc` exists. I tried to delay the injecting code with a timeout to see it it worked but it still doesnt, seems like `window.myfunc` doesn't get created at all no matter how much you delay. Can it be so `window` object inside myClass I am accssing it not the browsers `window` object?

Comment: @Bergi `api.js` is called after `window.myfunc = this.myfunc.bind(this);`. `window.myfunc` is defined immediately after `window.myfunc = this.myfunc.bind(this);` inside myClass but when I put  a breakpoint anywhere inside `api.js` `window.myfunc` is undefined. why is it so ?  is `window` inside myClass some local copy of windows and doesnt change the global `window` ?

Comment: yes apparently the two window objects are in different world ie main page and browser-extensions content script. Aparently there are unanswered questions on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64144684/chrome-extension-returned-window-variable-not-updating-in-extension-but-updati